# Symfony 2 : validate console command arguments

Tags: symfony, console

I am creating a command to generate accounts from a file. In command I have passed some arguments.

```
   $this
  ->setName('batch:create')
  ->setDescription('xyz')
  ->setHelp('xyz')
  ->addArgument('account-id', InputArgument::REQUIRED, "Set the account id.")
  ->addArgument('name', InputArgument::REQUIRED, "Set the account name.");
```

I was just thinking if there is any way I can check type of argument passed. For now I am checking it like this,

```
   if (is_numeric($input->getArgument('account-id'))) {
    // ....
   }
```

Is there anyway I can create a validator that checks the type and I just have to call validate function.

```
   if ($input->validate() === false) {
     // show error message and return.
   }
```

Comment: I've updated my answer with some new details, looks like we have a better solution now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately, currently there's no way to implement command argument validation in Symfony. The best way to implement these checks would be overriding `Symfony\Component\Console\Command::initialize` method in your command and then applying the validation rules there, throwing exceptions if passed arguments are invalid.

**Update:** Matthias Noback has implemented `symfony-console-form` (https://github.com/matthiasnoback/symfony-console-form), and looks like implementing `Matthias\SymfonyConsoleForm\Console\Command\FormBasedCommand` interface would give you basic validation abilities through the form component (have to test it with validation, though).

Comment: You are right. I think for now I have to keep my current code as it is.